# Imprimir listas en líneas independientes

Tags: python-3.x

Dadas dos variables:

```
a = [40, 10, 50, 10, 40, 50]
b = [25, 50, 25, 40, 10, 45]
```

Necesito imprimirlas de la siguiente manera:

```
([40, 10, 50, 10, 40, 50],
 [25, 50, 25, 40, 10, 45])
```

¿Alguien puede decirme cómo consigo que cada lista aparezca en una nueva línea?

Comment: ¿Así podría ser `print((a,b))`? O bien ¿así `print("({0},\n{1})".format(a,b))`?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Muchas gracias. Con el print("({0},\n{1})".format(a,b)) me ha salido justo como necesitaba.

Comment: Si has encontrado las solución a tu pregunta , no la pongas en la pregunta en si. Crea una respuesta y marca la como solución aceptada :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUCION:

```
print("({0},\n {1})".format(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer esto:

```
a = [40, 10, 50, 10, 40, 50]
b = [25, 50, 25, 40, 10, 45]

for l in [a, b]:
    print(repr(l) + '\n')
```

Sobre la funcion [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object....